# ¿CÓMO RECUPERAR DATOS INGRESADOS DE UN FORMULARIO, CON UN ID?

Tags: jquery, html5, json

Estoy realizando una página web que valora el estado de maduración de un proyecto de investigación. El flujo de acción es que el usuario crea un nuevo proyecto, ingresa los datos básicos (nombre del proyecto y participantes), se sube a la base de datos con ID auto incremento.

Después de eso, se pasa a la valoración, que tiene un total de 50 checkbox. Y se dividen en 9 grupos. Entre estos grupos, hay transiciones con información.

El problema está en que pueden pasar semanas y meses para llegar al último grupo de preguntas. Y el usuario, al regresar a la valoración, se ve obligado a realizar todo el proceso de nuevo.

Quisiera saber cómo, al seleccionar un proyecto para continuar el proceso, los checkbox que el usuario seleccionó, se muestren automáticamente. O sea, que guarde las respuestas y las reupere, sin subirlas a una base de datos.

No tengo código, porque los que he visto, sólo me guardan las respuestas, pero no las recupera.

Comment: No sé como lo vas a hacer sin guardar en BD, ¿quizás cookies? Entonces al iniciar sesión se recupera una cookie donde tienes codificados los estados de tus checks

Comment: Sí. Pienso que sería más fácil guardarlo en cookies. Si es así, no sé si sería mejor con JavaScript, o la cookie en PHP. Leo recomendaciones.